# Outlook Business Contact Manager with Remote Exchange via OWA

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I host an exchange 2010. 
Customers remotely can access that mailserver via their office 2013 and OWA, to send and receive Emails works like a charm. 
Now they want to use business contact manager. 
Is it possible use business contact manager somehow via https? 
My second idea is to set up an VPN between customer and exchange, in that case it will work definitely, but i would prefer a solution via https.